# unable to get or set the properties of prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, reflection, prototype

I am getting error when trying to get the keys of the object and all the objects of prototype objects, if present. It gives me an type error when trying to access keys of `prototype`. Whats wrong This works -

`Object.keys(object)`

`Object.keys(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(object.__proto__))`,

```
let obj = { "tester": 10 };
let ko = Reflect.ownKeys(obj);
let kp = Reflect.ownKeys(obj.prototype); // Error TypeError: Reflect.ownKeys called on non-object
let kp = Reflect.ownKeys(obj.__proto__); // Error TypeError: Reflect.ownKeys called on non-object
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj.prototype, null); // Error 
Object.freeze(obj.prototype); // Error
Object.freeze(obj);


let obj = { "tester": 10 };

let ko = Reflect.ownKeys(obj);
let kp = Reflect.ownKeys(obj.prototype); // Error TypeError: Reflect.ownKeys called on non-object

let oko = Object.keys(obj.__proto__); // Error TypeError: Reflect.ownKeys called on non-object
let okp = Object.keys(obj.prototype); // Error TypeError: Reflect.ownKeys called on non-object

let doko = Object.keys(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj.__proto__)); 
let dokp = Object.keys(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj.prototype)); // Error TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Object.setPrototypeOf(obj.prototype, null); // TypeError: Object.setPrototypeOf called on null or undefined 
Object.freeze(obj.prototype); // TypeError: Object.setPrototypeOf called on null or undefined
Object.freeze(obj);
```

Error is TypeError: Reflect.ownKeys called on non-object

```
TypeError: Reflect.ownKeys called on non-object
    at Reflect.ownKeys (<anonymous>)
    at copyProps (C:\Users\ganes\OneDrive\Documents\projects\freezeobject\index.js:68:29)
    at Object.makeSafe (C:\Users\ganes\OneDrive\Documents\projects\freezeobject\index.js:139:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ganes\OneDrive\Documents\projects\freezeobject\demos\demos.freezeobject.js:25:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1378:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1437:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.getPrototypeOf()` to access an object's prototype:

```js
let obj = { "tester": 10 };
console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)));
```

`__proto__` should work too but depricated:

```js
let obj = { "tester": 10 };
console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(obj.__proto__));
```

`prototype` is a property of a function/class to assign as `__proto__` to `this` with the function/class used as a constructor with `new`

```js
console.log((function(){}).prototype);
console.log((class{}).prototype);
console.log(({}).prototype);
```

And yes, you cannot freeze or set a prototype of `undefined`:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj.prototype, null); // Error 
Object.freeze(obj.prototype); // Error
```

And yes, `.prototype` !== `__proto__`:

```js
class Test{}
console.log(Test.__proto__);
console.log(Test.prototype === Test.__proto__);
```